# React JS | Cross fetch get all status code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, npm

I'm using [Cross fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch) for my ReactJS API calls

Is there a way to capture `400` `401`  & `403` in fetch response.

Here is sample code of using fetch

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    title: 'foo',
     body: 'bar',
     userId: 1
   }),
   headers: {
     "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
   }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
```

Comment: Try to add in the first `then` : `.then(response => { if(response.status===400) { console.log('status 400'); } return response.json() }`

Answer (score 1):

You can check the status code in the callback given to the first `then`:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    title: 'foo',
    body: 'bar',
    userId: 1
  }),
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  }
})
.then(response => {
  if ([400, 401, 403].includes(response.status)) {
    throw new Error('Response status was 400, 401, or 403!');
  }

  return response.json();
})
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Comment: It did not work as expected. It didn't show the msg. got `400` error on console not by code.

Comment: @Selvin It works when I try it. Are you sure you are testing the correct code? I updated the answer with a way of throwing an error, and loggin it in the `catch` instead.

Comment: this should work, it's used exactly the same way as the first example of the [readme](https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch). If it does not do what you want it's either because you're unclear with what you want or you are doing something elsewhere in your code that breaks this example

Comment: tried with updated code getting error like `Network request failed` on catch

Comment: @Selvin Then it's something else that makes the request not succeed. The `then` callback is never run.

Comment: @Tholle If it is `200` then `then` works. if it is `400` then `catch` works